# Setting a branch to a previous commit but keeping subsequent commits

Tags: git

I'm working on a large project that has a 'develop' branch. The develop branch is hooked up to our development server/environment. I recently made some changes that have been pushed to the develop branch, but I want to go back to before those changes to test a certain piece of functionality out. I'm wondering what the least destructive way to do that is. Ideally, I'd just like to revert the branch to that commit for a few minutes, and then return it to my current commit afterwards. I'm using Github.

Comment: `git checkout SHA` if you don't want to make changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git checkout <commit>` to put your working directory in the state it was at any commit. This will not update the HEAD of your develop branch and you can just move back there with a `git checkout develop`.

You can find out what the sha1 of the commit you are searching is with `git log`.